# Input JSON is invalid. Request body must be valid JSON if content type is application/json

Tags: jquery, json, content-type, jquery-ajaxq

I am passing the following `JSON object` to my AJAX call

```
var contact = {
   "accessToken": "xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx",
   "email": "test@test.com",
   "customFields": {
      "custom7": {"value": "test rep"},
      "custom8": {"value": "test title"},
      "custom9": {"value": "test@localdev.com"}
   }
}
```

And this is my AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'https://api.mydomain.com/v1/contacts/save',
   data: contact,
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(data) {
     alert(data.errors);
   }
});
```

`data.errors` shows the following:

> Input JSON is invalid.  Request body must be valid JSON if content
>   type is application/json

I checked above JSON object with [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com) and it was validated.
I don't understand where I am doing wrong!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

stringify that json before passing it through -

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'https://api.mydomain.com/v1/contacts/save',
    data: JSON.stringify(contact),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data.errors);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked. I however had to add `contentType: application/json` along with `dataType: json` !